# Class with multiple interfaces

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

i have 2 interfaces inter1 and inter2 and class that implements both of them:

```
public interface Interface1 {
    method1();
}
public interface Interface2 {
    method2();
}
public class Implementer implements Interface1, Interface2 {
    method1() { 
         // something 
    }
    method2() { 
         // something 
    } 
}
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface1 obj = quest();
        obj.method1();
        if(obj instanceof Interface2) {
            obj.method2(); //exception
        }    
    }

    public static Interface1 quest() {
        return new cl();
    }
}
```

How to cast obj to Interface2 and call method2() or it is possible to call method2() without casting ?

Comment: You could do cl obj = quest(); which will allow you to use both.

Comment: You should follow the naming conventions to make this a bit more readable.

Comment: `obj.method2(); //exception` - it's not an exception: that's something that happens at runtime. This would be a compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write `inter1 obj = ...` then you will not be able to write `obj.method2)` unless you cast to `inter2` or to a type that `implements inter2`.

For example

```
inter1 obj = quest();
if (obj instanceof class1)
    ((class1) obj).method2();
```

or

```
inter1 obj = quest();
if (obj instanceof inter2)
    ((inter2) obj).method2();
```

As an aside, when you write in Java you normally give classes and interfaces names that begin the a capital letter, otherwise you confuse people reading your code.

Comment: This is a bad practice. You should investigate on dependency injection, or inversion of control. Inject your Test class with 2 dependencies: an Interface1 and an Interface2. Your DI container would resolve both to the same object.

Comment: @sturcotte06 I agree. I was just answering the question directly, but you're right it's generally not a very good idea to use `instanceof` to check if an instance of one interface is also another.

Comment: @sturcotte06 how i can do it with DI framework, for example Spring. can you show short example?

Answer (score 1):

Using genecics it is possible to declare generic reference implementing more than one type. You can invoke method from each interface it implements without casting. Example below:

```
public class TestTwoTypes{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testTwoTypes();
    }

    static <T extends Type1 & Type2> void testTwoTypes(){
        T twoTypes = createTwoTypesImplementation();
        twoTypes.method1();
        twoTypes.method2();
    }

    static <T extends Type1 & Type2> T createTwoTypesImplementation(){
        return (T) new Type1AndType2Implementation();
    }
}

interface Type1{

    void method1();
}

interface Type2{
    void method2();
}

class Type1AndType2Implementation implements Type1, Type2{

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("method1");
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("method2");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
method1
method2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in spring, the general idea would be:

```
// Test.java
public class Test {
    private final Interface1 i1;
    private final Interface2 i2;
    public Test(Interface1 i1, Interface2 i2) {
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }
}

<!-- application-context.xml -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="implementer" class="org.mypackage.Implementer" />
    <bean id="test" class="org.mypackage.Test">
        <constructor-arg ref="implementer"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="implementer"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

// Main.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    Test t = (Test) context.getBean("test");
}
```